# Use of the word "local" to mean "domestic" or "national" in certain forms of English

Tags: word-usage, british-english, maltese-english

In Maltese English, it is very common to use the word “local” to mean "domestic" or "national" / "Maltese".

To give some context – Malta is a tiny independent island-state circa 17 miles by 9. English is one of the two official languages, since Malta was once a British colony. However, the English spoken in Malta by a large part of the native population - Maltese English - is very peculiar and the usage is completely different from that of British English.

Maltese products are described as "[local products](https://www.gov.mt/en/Government/DOI/Press%20Releases/Pages/2020/December/02/pr202455en.aspx)"; national news as "[local news](https://www.independent.com.mt/local)"; Maltese courts as "[local courts](https://timesofmalta.com/articles/view/why-a-maltese-case-could-shake-up-justice-systems-across-the-eu.747480)" and so on.

I suspect that this is the case because most Maltese think of Malta as a locality due to its size.

My question is whether this use of the word "local" is limited to Maltese English, or if it is used as such in other forms of English.

Comment: It's never used for 'national' (or 'regional') in everyday English in the UK. I don't know where to find proof positive for this, so no 'answer'.

Comment: This is probably because Malta is so tiny, perhaps also because it used to be a colony. In larger countries, "local" refers to smaller regions.

Comment: Local is a relative term for *near these parts*. If you labeled an island 25% the size of London a continent, you could still report on the continent's local weather.

Comment: The question asks whether 'this use of the word "local" is limited to Maltese English', without making it clear what 'this use' is. If 'this use' of *local* is the use for an area of approximately the same size as that of Malta, then then there is nothing about it that is peculiar to Maltese English - that's roughly how the term is used in all versions of English. On the other hand if 'this use' means the use in which it is synonymous with *domestic* or *national*, then this use is likely to be found only in the countries of  a comparable size.

Comment: You might look to Singapore as another geographically small nation with its own distinctive form of English. I would expect if the Straits Times says something about "local products" they are talking about products from somewhere in Singapore rather than from an even more smaller region. (But I have no evidence to back this up).

Comment: @jsw29 The first line of the question seems to make it clear. They say it means domestic or national. But as I said in my comment, it may derive from the common use to refer to a smaller region, and achieved this meaning because Malta is so small.